# how to make this mysql sub query work

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT c.noreg AS noreg, count( * ) AS jumlah
FROM kamar a, reservasi b, register c, identitas_psn d, sub_unit_kamar e
WHERE a.idkamar = b.kamar
AND b.noreg = c.id_reg_lengkap
AND c.norm = d.norm
AND c.idunit = e.id_subunit
AND c.noreg NOT
IN (

SELECT noreg
FROM register_keluar
)
AND (
c.idunit LIKE '20%'
)
AND jumlah > 1
GROUP BY noreg
ORDER BY jumlah DESC
```

// error is : AND jumlah > 1

Answer (score 2):

Move `jumlah > 1` into a `HAVING` clause, e.g.:

```
...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING jumlah > 1
ORDER BY ...
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL):

> A HAVING clause in SQL specifies that
>   an SQL SELECT statement should only
>   return rows where aggregate values
>   meet the specified conditions.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT c.noreg AS noreg, count( * ) AS jumlah
FROM kamar a, reservasi b, register c, identitas_psn d, sub_unit_kamar e
WHERE a.idkamar = b.kamar
AND b.noreg = c.id_reg_lengkap
AND c.norm = d.norm
AND c.idunit = e.id_subunit
AND c.noreg NOT
IN ( SELECT noreg FROM register_keluar AND c.idunit LIKE '20%') 
AND jumlah > 1
GROUP BY noreg
ORDER BY jumlah DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are combining the selection of any column and an aggregate alias (in your example: COUNT(*) as jumlah) and then you intend to use this aggregate alias (jumlah) somewhere in your query, with a *GROUP BY* condition, you need to use a *HAVING* condition after that corresponding GROUP BY.